# Compare lists and show the amount of matches until no match is found

Tags: python

I would like to Compare two lists and show the amount of matches until no match is found.

for example if i have

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

And then I shuffle each list, each time I shuffle the list I want to print out how many matches in the list I received for example

lets say they get shuffled one time and this is the output

```
shuffled_list1 = 2,4,5,3,1,6
shuffled_list2 = 2,4,5,1,3,6
```

from the output I would like to receive 3 matches found.since the six came after a non match I do not want that to be counted.

Comment: What do you mean by "after each time"?

Comment: There are lazily evaluated approaches that can avoid creating a list in memory.

Comment: These answers should be there, since OP there didn't specify a list for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
l = zip(list1, list2)
matches = len(list(filter(lambda item:item[0] == item[-1], l)))
```

Output -

```
4
```

Comment: This fits perfectly in with what I am trying to make !! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jfetto You can share the code. I can try to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

- zip to build pair of items across different list(based on index)
- break the loop if pair is not consisting same number
- otherwise count

```
count = 0
for i,j in zip(shuffled_list1,shuffled_list2):
    if i!=j:
        break
    count+=1
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

we suppose that list length are the same any time

```py
count = 0
for _ , i  in list1:
    if list1[i] == list2[i]:
         count = count +1
    break
print(str(count)+"matches")
```

Comment: using `zip` avoids the requirement that the lists be the same length

Comment: yeah zip is the best way